# Remove rows that do not have specific pair

Tags: r

My `df` contains pairs of samples and the pairs can be identified in `"IDs"`. I would like to remove pairs that do not contain a 1 in the `SampleTime`. In my example, sample 1049 only has 2 and 4 as SampleTime and both should therefore be remove.

```
                  Expr SampleTime  IDs
MMRF_1030_3_BM  33.515          3 1030
MMRF_1030_1_BM 5.37626          1 1030
MMRF_1049_4_BM 13.3217          4 1049
MMRF_1049_2_BM 82.4998          2 1049
MMRF_1079_2_BM 131.134          2 1079
MMRF_1079_1_BM 6.62901          1 1079
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `ave` to create a logical index for subsetting the rows.  Grouped by 'IDs', check for `any` value of 1 in 'SampleTime' and subset the rows

```
df1[with(df1, ave(SampleTime==1, IDs, FUN = any)),]
#                   Expr SampleTime  IDs
#MMRF_1030_3_BM  33.51500          3 1030
#MMRF_1030_1_BM   5.37626          1 1030
#MMRF_1079_2_BM 131.13400          2 1079
#MMRF_1079_1_BM   6.62901          1 1079
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, the same logic can be applied

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(IDs) %>%
    filter(any(SampleTime == 1))
```

Or another option is

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(IDs) %>%
   filter(1 %in% SampleTime)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[any(SampleTime == 1)], IDs]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Expr = c(33.515, 5.37626, 13.3217, 82.4998, 131.134, 
6.62901), SampleTime = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L), IDs = c(1030L, 
1030L, 1049L, 1049L, 1079L, 1079L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("MMRF_1030_3_BM", 
"MMRF_1030_1_BM", "MMRF_1049_4_BM", "MMRF_1049_2_BM", "MMRF_1079_2_BM", 
"MMRF_1079_1_BM"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `subset` `Ids` with `SampleTime = 1` and filter them from the entire dataset

```
subset(df, IDs %in% unique(IDs[SampleTime == 1]))

#                  Expr SampleTime  IDs
#MMRF_1030_3_BM  33.515          3 1030
#MMRF_1030_1_BM   5.376          1 1030
#MMRF_1079_2_BM 131.134          2 1079
#MMRF_1079_1_BM   6.629          1 1079
```

which can be written in `dplyr` as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(IDs %in% unique(IDs[SampleTime == 1]))
```

Or in `data.table` as

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[IDs %in% unique(IDs[SampleTime == 1])]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Expr = c(33.515, 5.37626, 13.3217, 82.4998, 131.134, 
6.62901), SampleTime = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L), IDs = c(1030L, 
1030L, 1049L, 1049L, 1079L, 1079L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("MMRF_1030_3_BM", "MMRF_1030_1_BM", "MMRF_1049_4_BM", "MMRF_1049_2_BM", 
"MMRF_1079_2_BM", "MMRF_1079_1_BM"))
```